# "set path" command preventing "xcopy" command to work

Tags: batch-file, cmd

When I need to extract a `.RAR` file using a `BAT` script I use the following command:

```
set path="path\to\installed\winrar\directoy"
WinRAR x "name of file.RAR"
```

In the next line if I try to give a `xcopy` command it says:

```
'xcopy' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program, or batch file.
```

Whereas if I run the `xcopy` command before issuing the `set path` command, it works without any issue.

How do I use the `xcopy` command AFTER giving the `set path` command?

Comment: because you broke the default `path` variable. rename the viariable to `mypath` like so `set "mypath=path\to\installed\winrar\directoy"` also notice the location of my double quotes.

Comment: Don't use `path` as a variable name. `%path%` tells the command prompt where to find it's executables (like `xcopy.exe`). Open a new command prompt and type `set`. Don't mess with any variables listed (unless you know exactly what you do, what they are for and how changing them influences your system)

Comment: At the end of `set /?` are some more variables listed, you shouldn't mess around with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To better explain this in more detail.

Windows has environment variables for both `System` and `User`. one of these variables is `path`.

`Path` is used as a default indexing variable which tells the system where to find files and executables. So for you `set`ting `path`, your `cmd` prompt no longer knows where to find the executables, unless you supply the full path to the executable BUT it should still never be done.

To understand it better:
open `cmd` and type `set path` or `echo %path%` and see the result.

Then do `set "path=some string"` then do `set path` or `echo %path%` again and notice how it changed.

So get to know your variables by running `set` from `cmd` to list all default variables, and ensure you do not use any of them when creating variables in batch-files. It can become VERY dangerous.

So, to wrap it up, to fix your issue, change `path` to something unique like `mypath`:

```
set "mypath=path\to\installed\winrar\directoy"
"%mypath%\WinRAR.exe" x "name of file.RAR"
```